# Why is this instance of strstr giving me segmentation faults?

Tags: c

Here is the full code

```
int count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub)
{
    char *ret;

    int a = 0; // used to tell where the pointer has moved to
    int count = 0;

    ret = strstr(str, sub);

    while (strstr(ret, sub) !=  NULL) {
        printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);

        for (a = 0; a < strlen(sub); a++) {
            ret++;
        }

        printf("The substring after moving pointer is: %s\n", ret);
        count++;
    }

    return count - 1;  
}
```

I don't understand what's happening here, I'm not using the null pointer once

```
strstr(ret,sub)
```

becomes null, so why is it giving me seg faults?

Valgrind would state that

Invalid read of size 1 and
 Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: If the first `strstr()` returns `NULL` (in `ret`), you are calling `strstr(NULL, ...)` in the while loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not test if the initial call `ret = strstr(str,sub);` succeeds.

If it returns `NULL`, the next call `strstr(ret,sub)` will definitely invoke undefined behavior.

Furthermore, your code does not update `ret` correctly in the `while` loop, you must set `ret` to the first char past the match, not merely advance it by the length of the match.  Here is a simpler version:

```
int count_substr(const char *str, const char *sub) {
    /* returns the number of non overlapping matches of sub in str */
    const char *ret = str;   
    int count = 0;

    if (ret && sub && *sub != '\0') {
        while ((ret = strstr(ret, sub)) != NULL) {
            ret += strlen(sub);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, placing an if to check if ret is null solved the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid your solution still would not work because you do not move `ret` past the match.

Comment: There is no real need to introduce `ret`. The code could very well work on `str` directly.

Comment: "*Furthermore, your code does not update ret correctly ...*" Please where is the effective difference between how much your code advances `ret` and the OP's code?

Comment: @alk: The OP's code only advances `ret` by the length of `sub` (with a `for` loop), whereas my code  first updates `ret` to point to the start of the match and then advances it by the length `sub`, effectively making it point to the first character after the match. Advancing by 1 would count overlapping matches, advancing by `strlen(sub)` counts non-overlapping matches.  The OP's code would erroneously return 2 for `count_substr("a","a");` and 4 for `count_substr("baab", "b");`

Comment: Yes, yes, sure. Hadn't had the 2nd coffee the moment I commented. Sry! :} Completely forget about "*whereas my code first updates `ret`*" again.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check return value of strstr (man strstr (3)):

> ```
> RETURN VALUE
>        These functions return a pointer to the beginning
>        of the located substring, or NULL if the substring is not found.
> ```